# Decode Gujarati font from Json service output android

Tags: android, json

hello friends i have following json

```
{
"category": [{
    "id": "90",
    "user_id": "1",
    "category_id": "27",
    "name": "આણંદ કોમર્સિયલ લેયર",
    "order": "0",
    "created_at": "2014-05-03 17:09:54",
    "updated_at": "2014-05-03 17:09:54",
    "deleted": "0",
    "subtopics": [{
        "id": "203",
        "user_id": "1",
        "category_id": "27",
        "subcategory_id": "90",
        "name": "આણંદ કોમર્સિયલ લેયર (સંકર જાત)",
        "order": "0",
        "details": "&lt;p style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;&lt;img alt=\"\" src=\"/packages/wysiwyg/ckeditor/plugins/kcfinder/upload/images/1.png\" style=\"height:271px; width:237px\" /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;ul&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;પ્રથમ ઈંડું મુક્વાની સરેરાશ ઉંમર:૧૪૨ દિવસ&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;સરેરાશ વાર્ષિક ઈંડા ઉત્પાદન : ૩૦૦ ઈંડા&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;૪૦ અઠવાડીયાની ઉંમરે ઈંડાનું સરેરાશ વજન : ૫૨ ગ્રામ&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;૭૨ અઠવાડીયાની ઉંમરે ઈંડાનું સરેરાશ વજન : ૫૪ ગ્રામ&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;સારી જીવાદોરી&lt;/li&gt;\r\n&lt;/ul&gt;\r\n",
        "mobile_detail": "&lt;p style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;&lt;img alt=\"\" src=\"/packages/wysiwyg/ckeditor/plugins/kcfinder/upload/images/1.png\" style=\"height:271px; width:237px\" /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;\r\n\r\n&lt;ul&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;પ્રથમ ઈંડું મુક્વાની સરેરાશ ઉંમર:૧૪૨ દિવસ&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;સરેરાશ વાર્ષિક ઈંડા ઉત્પાદન : ૩૦૦ ઈંડા&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;૪૦ અઠવાડીયાની ઉંમરે ઈંડાનું સરેરાશ વજન : ૫૨ ગ્રામ&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;૭૨ અઠવાડીયાની ઉંમરે ઈંડાનું સરેરાશ વજન : ૫૪ ગ્રામ&lt;/li&gt;\r\n\t&lt;li style=\"text-align:justify\"&gt;સારી જીવાદોરી&lt;/li&gt;\r\n&lt;/ul&gt;\r\n",
        "created_at": "2014-05-03 17:11:43",
        "updated_at": "2014-05-11 13:41:31",
        "deleted": "0",
        "images": [],
        "videos": []
    }]
}]
}
```

Method for post:

```
public Object getAppData(GetCategoryData mGetFlag) {

    nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", StaticValues.mStringEmail));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", StaticValues.mStringPassword));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", StaticValues.mStringId));

    return postHttpURLWithPostMethodTour(AllUrls.mStringWebApiLink + "api/apps", nameValuePairs, mGetFlag);
}
```

So i make service call with post parameter like:

```
 public Object postHttpURLWithPostMethodTour(String url, List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs, Object mObject) {
HttpPost httppost;
HttpParams httpParameters;
int timeoutConnection = 60000;
HttpClient httpclient = null;
HttpResponse response = null;
String data = "";
isOtherError = false;

System.out.println("Url " + url);
mFillObject = null;

if (check_Internet()) {
    try {
        mFillObject = mObject.getClass().newInstance();
        URL urlToRequest = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

        httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        httppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        httppost.addHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
        httppost.addHeader("mobile-tokon", StaticValues.mStringMobileToken);

        httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);


        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        if (nameValuePairs != null) {
            for (int index = 0; index < nameValuePairs.size(); index++) {
                String paramName = nameValuePairs.get(index).getName();
                String paramValue = nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue();

                System.out.println("paramName " + paramName);
                System.out.println("paramValue " + paramValue);


                if (paramName.equalsIgnoreCase("image")) {
                    if (paramValue.length() > 0) {
                        System.out.print("File Object found");
                        entity.addPart(paramName, new FileBody(new File(paramValue)));

                    }
                } else {
                    entity.addPart(nameValuePairs.get(index).getName(), new StringBody(nameValuePairs.get(index).getValue()));

                }
            }
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
        }

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


        System.out.println("httppost " + httppost.toString());
        data = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        System.out.println("Final Data " + data);
        mStringresponse = data;
        if (data.equalsIgnoreCase("{\"is_device_deleted\":true}"))
            setDeviceToken(true);
        mFillObject = mGson.fromJson(data, mFillObject.getClass());


      } catch (Exception e) {
        isOtherError = true;
     }
  }
return mFillObject;
  }
```

But when i call this i get output like bellow:

> httppost org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost@5359a64c at line  httppost.toString()

So any idea how can i resolve this? your all suggestions are appreciable.

Comment: Have you try this post method before?

Comment: Er. Arjun saini : yes in my many old projects i tried this and it is working fine

Comment: I am also work Like your Post Service....Can you try this With Async Task

Comment: Er. Arjun saini: i already call this with asynctask

Comment: I Post my Code Soon Try with this......

Comment: Er. Arjun sain : Okay,

Answer (score 0):

Why would you print out the post object?  That makes no sense.  You want to print out the result, not the post object.  The reason that's the output has nothing to do with the font-  that's what it prints out because the post object doesn't have a better toString function.  It would print that out even if all of the result was in english.

Comment: Gabe Sechan: i comment this line but now i didn't get output

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Code**

```
private class AysncTaskSend extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {
        private ProgressDialog regDialog=null;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            
        }       
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try 
            {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value1",
                                "Value1"));
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value2",
                                "value2"));
                        
                        String response = null;
                        try {
                            response = SimpleHttpClient
                                    .executeHttpPost("url",
                                            postParameters);
                             res = response.toString();

                             return res;
                            
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            errorMsg = e.getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);


                //  error.setText(resp);
                    if (null != errorMsg && !errorMsg.isEmpty()) {
                        
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            

  // do what u do
    }
```

**SimpleHttpClient.java**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class SimpleHttpClient {
 /** The time it takes for our client to timeout */
    public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds

    /** Single instance of our HttpClient */
    private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

    /**
     * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.
     *
     * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set
     */
    private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (mHttpClient == null) {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return mHttpClient;
    }

    public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
    }

    
    public static String executeHttpatch(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
    }

    /**
     * Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.
     *
     * @param url The web address to post the request to
     * @return The result of the request
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    }
    finally {
        if (in != null) {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

**Used for Some Import easily download**

> apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar
>
> httpclient-4.2.3.jar
>
> Add Your entity part as you add

Comment: Er. Arjun saini : i have header input parameter so where i have to set it GET and POST method?

Comment: You directly call the SimpleHttpClient .executeHttpPost for post and for get SimpleHttpClient .executeHttpGet